# Under what conditions does $H(X\mid f(Y))=H(X\mid Y)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains, entropy

I have the problem that I cannot solve:
Under what conditions does $H(X∣f(Y))=H(X∣Y)$?
I would like to draw a result about the relation between $p_X(\cdot | g(Y))$ and $p_X(\cdot | Y)$. Are they equal?

This is an exercise in the textbook. There is a solution, but I don't think it's correct (more precisely, it is not satisfactory enough). The provided solution is as below.

Suggested Solution (not satisfactory). If $H(X|g(Y )) = H(X|Y )$, then $H(X)−H(X|g(Y )) = H(X) − H(X|Y )$, i.e., $I(X; g(Y )) = I(X; Y )$. This is the condition for equality in the data processing inequality. From the derivation of the inequality, we have equality iff $X → g(Y ) → Y$ forms a Markov chain. Hence $H(X|g(Y )) = H(X|Y )$ iff $X → g(Y ) → Y$ . This condition includes many special cases, such as $g$ being one-to-one, and $X$ and $Y$ being independent. However, these two special cases do not exhaust all the possibilities.

Comment: "it is not satisfactory enough" Why?

Comment: I would like to draw a result about the relation between $p_X(\cdot | g(Y))$ and $p_X(\cdot | Y)$.

Comment: I would add when $ \mathbb{E} \left[ X \mid Y \right] = \mathbb{E} \left[ X \mid f \left( Y \right) \right] $ and $ {p}_{X} \left( \cdot \mid Y \right) = {p}_{X} \left( \cdot \mid f \left( Y \right) \right) $. Clearly when $ {p}_{X} \left( \cdot \mid Y \right) = {p}_{X} \left( \cdot \mid f \left( Y \right) \right) $ all are equal.

Comment: @Royi, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I said you should extend the question to the cases I wrote above in addition to what you wrote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data processing inequality lemma already provides the complete answer. $I(X;Y)=I(X;g(Y))$ holds if and only if $$\tag{1}X\rightarrow Y \rightarrow g(Y)$$ and $$\tag{2} X\rightarrow g(Y) \rightarrow Y.$$

Now note that 
$$
\begin{align}
p(x,g(y),y) &= p(y, g(y))p\left(x\mid y, g(y)\right)\\
&=p(y, g(y))p\left(x\mid y\right)\tag{3},
\end{align}
$$
where the last equality holds since (1) implies that $g(Y)\rightarrow Y \rightarrow X$, i.e., $X$ is independent of $g(Y)$, when conditioned on $Y$. Also note that 
 $$
\begin{align}
p(x,g(y),y) &= p(y, g(y))p\left(x\mid y, g(y)\right)\\
&=p(y, g(y))p\left(x\mid g(y)\right) \tag{4},
\end{align}
$$
where the last equality holds since (2) implies $Y\rightarrow g(Y) \rightarrow X$.

It follows from (3) and (4) that it must hold 
$$
p\left(x\mid g(y)\right) = p(x \mid y),
$$
for all valid values of $x$ and $y$. This is the most general condition you seek, which captures the cases of $g$ being one to one and $Y$ independent of $X$.

Comment: What if it was extended to under which conditions $ \mathbb{E} \left[ X \mid Y \right] = \mathbb{E} \left[ X \mid g \left( Y \right) \right] $?

Comment: Thanks for your solution @Stelios.